# Javascript - Regex for comma-separated alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric

I need regex for

> validating comma separated alphanumeric String with length of 3-5
>   chars.
>
> string may or may not contain commas.
>
> each string will MUST have 3 to 6 numbers and One M in the end.

example-

```
12345M
1234M,12345M,11111M
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var re = /^(\d{3,6}M\,)*\d{3,6}M$/
```

Example code

```
console.log(re.test("1234M,12345M,11111M"));  // true
console.log(re.test("12345M"));               // true
console.log(re.test("12345M,"));              // false
```